# Converting typescript code to composition API(setup) in Vue3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement context menu when right mouse click.

**▼ This code below is working well.**

```
<template>
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px;background:red;" @contextmenu="onContextMenu1($event)" >
        Right Mouse Click Here
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { MenuOptions } from '../components/ContextMenuDefine';

export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    onContextMenu1(e : MouseEvent) {
      //prevent the browser's default menu
      e.preventDefault();
      //show our menu
      this.$contextmenu({
        items: [
          { 
            label: 'This is menu in parent box',
          },
          { 
            label: 'Simple item',
          },
        ],
        iconFontClass: 'iconfont',
        customClass: "class-a",
        zIndex: 3,
        minWidth: 230,
        x: e.x,
        y: e.y
      } as MenuOptions);
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

**▼ But This code below doesn't work.**

When i click right it cause error
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$contextmenu')"

```
<template>
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px;background:red;" @contextmenu="onContextMenu1($event)" >
        Right Mouse Click Here
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { MenuOptions } from '../../src/ContextMenuDefine';

const onContextMenu1 = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    this.$contextmenu({
        items: [
          { 
            label: 'This is menu in parent box',
          },
          { 
            label: 'Simple item',
          },
        ],
        iconFontClass: 'iconfont',
        customClass: "class-a",
        zIndex: 3,
        minWidth: 230,
        x: e.x,
        y: e.y
      } as MenuOptions);
}
</script>
```

I think there should be an alternative for 'this.$contextmenu' I can't find the way..T_T
It will be helpful any kind of comment :)

Comment: `this` should not be used in script setup and lambda functions. It usually points to the `window` object.

Comment: Not sure why this question had a react tag.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$contextmenu`it like vue2。
You should use vue3 library

```
npm i -S v-contextmenu@next
```

https://github.com/heynext/v-contextmenu